# Math symbols not working in mdpi template

Tags: equations, mdpi

I am using mdpi latex template.

```
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex,sensors]{Definitions/mdpi} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
```

these are the predefined packages.
Now, when ever I write equation

```
\begin{equation}
 Pr(T\leq t;\eta)=1-exp[-(\dfrac{t}{}^)], t>0
 \end{equation}
```

it gives me the following error
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "template".tex

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\nirbh\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log

Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\nirbh\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log

Process exited with error(s)

but if I remove \eta it will work.

Any help regarding this issue. It is only happening in mdpi template only. Rest in other calls or template it works well.

Comment: The `mdpi` LaTeX class does not appear to be part of the main TeX distributions, and it doesn't appear to be on the CTAN either. Are `mdpi.cls` and related files available online somewhere?

Comment: https://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex i downloaded it from here.

Comment: Are you sure that `\eta` is the cause of the problems? To me, the output of `-(\dfrac{t}{}^)` looks completely messed up.

Comment: ``\begin{equation}
Pr(T\leq t;\eta,\beta)=1-exp[-(\dfrac{t}{\eta}^\beta)], t>0
\end{equation}``

Comment: this is my complete equation, but when I remove ``\eta`` and ``\beta`` it works. Also, I tried inline math by using ``$ \eta $``, it doesn't work.

Comment: Probably not your bug, but the class loads `mathpazo`, which is long in the tooth but should still work. You don’t want to load `amsfonts` or `amssymb` on top; if you want to override `pazo` with any other font, it should be the update `newpxmath`, and if you want to load any additional math alphabets, use `mathalpha` or `isomath`. It also loaded `amsmath` already.

Comment: I tried to add ``mathalpha`` and ``newpxmath`` but getting the same error.

Comment: It is working now. I just update miketex.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was solved by a software update